# Regex not working on email domain selection properly

Tags: javascript, regex, email, email-validation, aura.js

```js
var str = "sdhdhh@gmail.com"; // true but coming false
var str1 = "sdhdhh@gmail.co.uk"; 
var str2 = "sdhdhh@gmail.org";
var str3 = "sdhdhh@gmail.org.uk";
var patt = new RegExp("[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+?[\.com]?[\.org]?[\.co.uk]?[\.org.uk]$");
console.log( str + " is " + patt.test(str));
console.log( str1 + " is " + patt.test(str1));
console.log( str2 + " is " + patt.test(str2));
console.log( str3 + " is " + patt.test(str3));
```

Can anyone tell me what is the mistake, my .com example is not working properly

Comment: You need a grouping construct and a regex literal, `var patt = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+?(?:\.com|\.org|\.co\.uk|\.org\.uk)$/;`

Comment: You should anchor the pattern with `^` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

- A grouping construct instead of character classes
- A regex literal notation so that you do not have to double escape special chars
- The `^` anchor at the start of the pattern since you need both `^` and `$` to make the pattern match the entire string.

So you need to use

```js
var patt = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+?(?:\.com|\.org|\.co\.uk|\.org\.uk)$/;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FWFEKf/1).

If you need to make it case insensitive, add `i` flag,

```js
var patt = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+?(?:\.com|\.org|\.co\.uk|\.org\.uk)$/i;
```